# On event JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I need to create landing page where you need to enter promotion code to proceed. There are 3 different actions: you enter correct code and redirected to another page, you have entered wrong code and redirected to error page and you left field blank. Every action should call own dialog box where you get message. I'm not programmer so I searched over Internet and found something.

Here's the JavaScript I use

```
// REDIRECT
function checkCode(){

// CODE CORRECT
if(document.getElementById('code').value === '123456'){
    //alert('Correct code 1'); 
    location.href = "http://google.com";
} 

// EMPTY CODE
else if (document.getElementById('code').value === ''){
    //alert('You have left field blank. Try again.'); 
    //location.href = "http://google.com";
} 

// WRONG ACTION
else {
    //alert('Wrong code');
    location.href = "fail.html";
    return false;
}
}

//DIALOG SUCCESS
$( function dialogSuccess() {
    $( "#dialog-success" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function dialog() {
        $( "#dialog-success" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});

//DIALOG EMPTY
$( function dialogError() {
    $( "#dialog-error" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function dialog() {
        $( "#dialog-error" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});

//DIALOG EMPTY
$( function dialogEmpty() {
    $( "#dialog-empty" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function dialog() {
        $( "#dialog-empty" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});

// MULTIPLE FUNC    

function checkFunc() {
    checkCode();
    dialogSuccess();
}
```

And HTML itself:

```
<form name=method="post" action="">

        <div class="listen">
            <h2>Enter 6-digit code:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="listen">
            <input type="text" maxlength="6" id="code" placeholder="XXXXXX" name="6digit" />
        </div>
        <div class="listen">
            <input class="orangebutton" id="opener" type="button" value="Proceed" onclick="checkFunc()" />
        </div>
    </form>

<div id="dialog-empty" title="Error">
    <p>You have left field blank. Try again.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-error" title="Error">
    <p>You have entered wrong code. Try again.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-success" title="Success">
    <p>Congratulations! You will be proceeded to google.com.</p>
</div>
```

So basically I need if I enter correct code function dialogSuccess() to be called in //code correct, if I enter wrong code, function called dialogError to be called from //wrong action. And if I leave field blank, the function dialogEmpty to be called in //empty code. Or maybe another way will be to change id "opener" on submit button.  Also it would be nice to have some delay if code correct and wrong action before redirection.

Comment: why do you use javascript to get a DOM element in one part and then jquery for the next?

Comment: you realise that doing this in JavaScript is completely insecure and any user with a small amount of knowledge could easily bypass your code entirely? If you want to prevent abuse of this you need to have your page send the code to a server-side script which can verify it. And any page you redirect to which is part of your site and requires the user to have entered a correct code beforehand must also check the user's identity and credentials before allowing access, in case someone tries to go directly there without visiting the landing page.

Comment: i know that. it doesn't need to be secured. this code  redirection is not something special and doesn't contain any secret data. as i said i'm not familiar with JS and jQuery. so i used code i found in internet.

Comment: Ok, that's fine, it was just so everyone is clear. Anyway...what exactly is your question? You've given us some code without explaining what it currently does and what features are missing from it. We've got some "i need" and "it would be nice to have" statements (and a "maybe" which doesn't help clarity of intent either), but with no indication of whether you've made any attempt to implement them, or what issue precisely you've faced in doing so. This isn't a free write-my-code service, but we will help you with your attempt if you've tried to do some research and a bit of code yourself too

Comment: Ok i thought i explained properly. 
As you see there are 3 different divs with messages that should be called on event (entering correct code, entering incorrect code and leaving code field blank).
Currently i can't call certain dialog box on certain event. For example if i enter correct code, function dialogSuccess should be called in event called //code correct. Or another way i see is to change id of submit button on event (currently id is #opener but it could be changed to #opener-success

Comment: changing IDs is not a good idea - the ID should uniquely identify the element and stay permanent, so you always know what you're referring to. To indicate a change of state you could set a class or a data- attribute

Comment: Anyway what do you mean by "can't"...surely you just need something like `if(document.getElementById('code').value === '123456'){
    //alert('Correct code 1'); 
   dialogSuccess();
    location.href = "http://google.com";
}` BTW why have you wrapped all your functions inside jQuery constructors? That makes no sense, not sure that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery script, it is better to use only jquery. Looks like you are using jquery dialogbox and want to open as per condition. Here is code you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function checkCode(){
var value=$("#code").val();

if( value=== '123456'){
     $( "#dialog-success" ).dialog( "open" );
    //location.href = "http://google.com";
} 

else if (value === ''){
  
    $( "#dialog-empty" ).dialog( "open" );
    //location.href = "http://google.com";
} 

else {
   $( "#dialog-error" ).dialog( "open" );
   // location.href = "fail.html";
    return false;
}
}

// MULTIPLE FUNC    
$( function() {
 $( "#dialog-success" ).dialog( {
  autoOpen: false
});
 $( "#dialog-error" ).dialog( {
  autoOpen: false
} );
 $( "#dialog-empty" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false
} );
});

function checkFunc() {
    checkCode();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name=method="post" action="">

        <div class="listen">
            <h2>Enter 6-digit code:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="listen">
            <input type="text" maxlength="6" id="code" placeholder="XXXXXX" name="6digit" />
        </div>
        <div class="listen">
            <input class="orangebutton" id="opener" type="button" value="Proceed" onclick="checkFunc()" />
        </div>
    </form>

<div id="dialog-empty" title="Error">
    <p>You have left field blank. Try again.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-error" title="Error">
    <p>You have entered wrong code. Try again.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-success" title="Success">
    <p>Congratulations! You will be proceeded to google.com.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need that. But something like this could do what you want:

```js
// REDIRECT
$("#opener").on('click', function(){
  var code = $('#code').val();
  $("#dialog-success, #dialog-empty, #dialog-error").addClass("hidden")
  if(code === '123456'){
      dialogSuccess()
  }else if (code === ''){
      dialogEmpty();
  }else {
      dialogError()
  }
})


//DIALOG SUCCESS
function dialogSuccess() {
  $("#dialog-success").removeClass("hidden");
}

//DIALOG EMPTY
function dialogError() {
  $("#dialog-error").removeClass("hidden");
}

//DIALOG EMPTY
function dialogEmpty() {
  $("#dialog-empty").removeClass("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">

        <div class="listen">
            <h2>Enter 6-digit code:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="listen">
            <input type="text" maxlength="6" id="code" placeholder="XXXXXX" name="6digit" />
        </div>
        <div class="listen">
            <input class="orangebutton" id="opener" type="button" value="Proceed" />
        </div>
    </form>

<div id="dialog-empty" title="Error" class="hidden">
    <p>You have left field blank. Try again.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-error" title="Error" class="hidden">
    <p>You have entered wrong code. Try again.</p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-success" title="Success" class="hidden">
    <p>Congratulations! You will be proceeded to google.com.</p>
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yfhua03w/16/)

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i want. These divs with messages are acting like dialog boxes (source from https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and replacing defauld javascript alert box.

Comment: @ArtjomKorman Instead of `$("#box-id").removeClass("hidden");` inside those functions add appropriate code for dialog boxes.